# SD Card Reader not working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sd-card, card-reader

I have a read many other posts on this issue and believe that Ubuntu 12.04 is not even recognizing my SD Card Reader as just that:

- Computer Model: Metabox (Australian builder of Clevo laptops) / Clevo
  P150EM
- OS: Ubuntu 12.04 (64 Bit)
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3720QM CPU @ 2.60GHz
- HD: 120GB Intel 550/520MB/s SSD

According to the people who built my computer, the specs of the SD Card reader in my comp are as follows:

- Manufacture: Realtek Semiconduct Corp.
- Location: PCI bus 3
- Hardware ID: PCI\Ven_10EC&DEV_5289&SUBSYS_51051558
- Physical device object name: \Device\NTPNP_PCI0015

Here are the relevant outputs of the following commands run from the terminal:

```
sudo lshw

 *-generic UNCLAIMED
                description: Unassigned class
                product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:f6a00000-f6a0ffff


sudo lspci -v -nn

03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5289] (rev 01)

    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:5105]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 4
    Memory at f6a00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=1 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
```

Does the unassigned details of these outputs mean that Ubunutu desn't know that the SD Card Reader is one and what do with it? and if so how should I go about fixing it??

Cheers ;)

Comment: I have managed to get the card reader working and it automounts fine as well

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/971876 This also works for asus x401a under 12.04

Comment: Bug was fixed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/971876

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution provided here works:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/971876

You can also just open the .deb file in the Software Centre and install it from there which works as well